# Using a hash function as a key in a dictonary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project I'm creating (in python 3.3) and I'm trying to figure out if there is a efficient (or prettier way) to do the following.

I have a function that extracts binary/hex strings like the following (groups of bits are split for example purposes only)

- 0000 1111 0002 0001
- 0000 1111 0003 0001
- 0000 1111 0002 0002
- 0000 1110 0002 0001

Now, what I want to do is to be able to pass these into a function and then fire them into a method depending on the values in the second group of bits, and the forth group of bits (that are opcodes)
eg; a hash function that will check to see if (* 1111 * 0001) matches and then return a function related to these bits.

I had the idea of using a dictionary of hash tables, however I'm not fully sure how one would make a key a mask.

While I could make a dictionary with the key 11110001 and the value the function I want to return, and then just concatting and passing in [4:8][12:16] would work, I was wondering if there was a way to make a hash function for a key. (if that makes sense) without going into a class and overriding the hash function and then passing that in.

Perhaps some form of data structure that stores regex keys and performs it on any valid input? - Whilst I could create one I'm wondering if there is some form of in-built function I'm missing (just so I don't reinvent the wheel)

Hopefully this makes sense!
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Can't you simply use The string `"1111 0001"` as a key in the dictionary?

Comment: Yup at current that would work! But I'd like something a bit more efficient and cleaner than splitting and concatting strings - and more flexible like a hash function, just in case  I needed something like ???? 1111 ???1 0001 in the future.

Comment: Are these actually strings? It seems more natural to represent them as ints and use bitwise operations. Also, if you want to map bit patterns to operations, you might want to consider using a list.

Comment: Yeah, I'm grabbing them from a text file so they are currently represented as strings. I thought about using bitwise operations and just "and" masking them but I did not know if there was a in-built feature that allowed me to set my own hashfunction on keys. 
Would you be able to explain more about considering using a list? - Do you mean setting the indexes as the value of 11110001 (22813045) for example?

Comment: Python `dict`s call the `__hash__` method so you don't have many choices: 1) Transform the string into some other *built-in* type and use it as a key(e.g. like my suggestion using some slice of the original string as key), or 2) Create a custom object with its custom `__hash__` method. I still don't understand how you want to use these things, without more context I really can't tell what would be better.

Comment: It's a sort of cross platform emulator of sorts, takes in a record file of binary groups and then maps the result to a higher level function. If 0001111100020001 was given, and 11110001 was the opcode to add, it would throw 0001 and 0002 together and add them and return the value (simplified to ignore registers etc) so being able to put those strings into a loop and just pass in each string and have it work its magic seems like a good idea and one that would be quite readable later on. (needs to be as modular as possible so adding new opcodes etc is as simple as adding a key->function pair)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to avoid implementing a tiny class with `__hash__` and `__eq__`. Dictionaries do support custom hash functions, and that is the way to do it:

```
KEY_MASK = 0xf0f0  # or whichever mask you need

class Key(object):
    __slots__ = 'num',
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.num & KEY_MASK)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.num & KEY_MASK == other.num & KEY_MASK
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self == other
```

Comment: I guess this makes sense, it's not really going to be terribly resource intensive - however I was shying away from creating a key class, just because there might be about 10k-320k+ of these objects in memory at a time and for efficiency sake would rather cut down on memory overhead. I come from a C background I've always been of a mindset not to use objects unless it was necessary and instead move the logic dealing with the primitive into a singleton subclass to process it. (such as a subclassed dictionary with get methods for hashing)
This seems be the most straightforward way though. Thanks!

Comment: @Nathan I've amended the class to use `__slots__` for reduced memory usage (no `__dict__` and weakref overhead). I think one's C instincts don't carry over well to Python. Unless you can prove you will have memory problems, you should first try the idiomatic solution (with optimization hints such as `__slots__`) and then, if there are problems, optimize it.

Comment: Note that in python3.3 object `__dict__` s can share keys, so the amount of memory used will be really small anyway. Avoid premature optimization!

Comment: @Bakuriu Key sharing doesn't help here because all `Key` object's dicts will have a single entry, which is quite inefficient (not to mention that even creating an empty `dict` costs memory). Adding `__slots__` to a class whose instances are known to be numerous and which is used for a very specific purpose is not a premature optimization - it's exactly what `__slots__` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are actually using the bit values from the examples so why not just derive a dictionary from dictionary that has a new method getmasked which masks the value before looking it up...

Comment: Good idea, so this would just entail subclassing dictionary and overriding the get method to do my hash function before calling the base dictionary method?
In this case would implementing a MutableMapping class do what I want?
Thanks for the help!